# Patch Panel Confusion

Tags: patch-panel

I am currently picking up a job that has been half completed!

At present, there are five patch panels, four of which are dotted around the building connecting to offices. These have a fiber line routing back to the main networking room.

The issue I have is that there is another patch panel, with 400+ jacks in the networking room.

However the number of patch panel ports doesn't amount to the same number as in the networking room panel.

So is it possible to go patch panel to network room and port in a office? The issue in testing is that the patch panels currently don't correlate to any port on the wall, and the network room has a different numbering system, so I don't really want to test 400+ ports at this stage!

Comment: I'm confused. A diagram would greatly help. Each TR has patch panels going to the WAs (copper?) and fiber back to the ER. Does the ER patch panel also go to the WAs? Does the ER include any which are for servers and such that may also be on the patch panel. It is important to get a consistent labeling standard, and it could affect how the AHJ treats this installation. You should also have test results from the installer, and that should have cable numbers included.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what kind of answer you expect.

You have to figure out how the cabling is done. There must be some kind of logic and you should be able to find it without testing all 400 cables.

You have to use a tone generator and a probe to identify in which panel a few jacks are connected and how each patch panel is linked to the main patch in the networking room.

Looking to the numbering at each side you should be able to guess the logic in the numbering... if there's any.

Comment: This is why we have ANSI/TIA/EIA-606, Administration Standard for Commercial Telecommunications Infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, if everything is fiber...  One possible, quick and dirty approach - assuming you have access to a pair of Cisco switches.

On the "office patch panel", connect some portion of the ports, let's say 48, to every port of the first switch. Go to the main room and look for active ports using your second switch. Spanning-tree should allow for multiple connections. When all found, run "show cdp neighbors" and write down the inter-connected ports. When done, a decent chunk of your 400 main room panel ports would be mapped. Continue with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Second thought. It would be very unusual to have every "office panel" port to be connected directly to the main networking room panel port. You'd rather have some number of fiber links between the panels (and main room panels meant to connect to the server side switches or servers themselves). BTW, in one case I have seen "the main room" panel was not meant to be a part of computer network at all, it was a part of some ancient phone system.